# Dynamic values in HTML Dropdown through ajax or through a function call

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, postgresql, flask

Please forgive my lack of knowledge as I am pretty new to flask,ajax, jquery,javascript and stuff.

In my project, in the backend,I have a basic Postgres database with a UUID primary key and a 'name' column. I need to get the distinct names from this column onto a HTML dropdown button on frontend. I am using flask and python.

On searching, I found answers to do this in two ways..

Through a function call as described here [Populating dropdown dynamically from list with Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690257/populating-dropdown-dynamically-from-list-with-jinja)

Another is do it with a ajax call using jquery and more.

Please let me know if possible, what method is more secure.
thanks in advance,
Abhi...

Comment: You only want to know which one is more secure? They are both secure. However if you're using Flask, Jinja is the obvious way to do it.

Comment: this post https://www.lifewire.com/when-to-use-ajax-3466246 may help you making the decision, but it seems that the logic of your app (as you described) don't need to perform `ajax` calls, just use `jinja` to render the dropdown

Comment: Thanks both of you @Wimanicesir and cizario . I dont know but, using ajax seems to be a bit tricky to me, whereas a function call(jinja) seems to be more easy. I want to send data along with html button values to backend(sql) and later receieve also if needed.